# Getting real ads instead of test ads on emulator and device

Tags: android, ads, admob

I am using the correct guidelines for viewing a test ad and logcat also shows it as a test device but the ads are real ads without displaying "Test Ad".

I am using the following code for generating the ad request:

```
public static AdRequest getNewAdrequest()
{
    if (isDebugBuild()) {
        String android_id = Settings.Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
        String deviceId = md5(android_id).toUpperCase();
        AdRequest adRequest =  new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice(deviceId).addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR).build();
        boolean isTestDevice = adRequest.isTestDevice(context);
        return adRequest;
    }
    else
    {
       return new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice("4CA0623922B985F481ACC93F908C7850").build();
    }
}

public static String md5(String md5) {
    try {
        java.security.MessageDigest md = java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        byte[] array = md.digest(md5.getBytes());
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
            sb.append(Integer.toHexString((array[i] & 0xFF) | 0x100).substring(1,3));
        }
        return sb.toString();
    } catch (java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
    }
    return null;
}
```

Log cat shows that its a test ad:

```
I/Ads: Starting ad request.
This request is sent from a test device.
```

But the ads are like these ones:
[image: ad1]
[image: ad2]

I am not using firebase. Using:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:12.0.0'
```

Tested on genymotion and also hardware device. Can't figure out whats wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You have use [Test ads](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads) unit ID to check test ads. As after some hours real ads are displayed.